# passing a value to Controller from View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a link and Combobox in View :

```
    <p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "CreateArticle")
    </p>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
 @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.TitleIds, new SelectList(ViewBag.TitleNames as System.Collections.IEnumerable, "TitleId", "Title.TitleText"), "No: " + (string) ViewBag.MagNo, new { id = "TitleIds" })
break;
}
```

I want to whenever i clicked on link "Create New", the selected value of DropDownListFor be passed to Controller "CreateArticle"?
how should i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very hard to understand what this page is susposed to do. But lets have a stab at it.

First off you need to read up on MVC and how you create forms. However if you want to conventionally post data your controller you (lets leave aJax out of this) will need a `<form>` tag this can be done using the html helper such as.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm()){
   //form contents here
}
```

Next your will need to submit your form some how. This can be done through a button.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm()){
       //form contents here
       <button type="submit">submit</button>
}
```

Now that we have the basics sorted. The above code will simply submit the form to the current controller action. To submit your form to a specific controller action you must modify your `BeginForm` helper. Such as.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateArticle", "Default"))
{
    //form contolls here
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
})
```

Great now the form is posting to your `CreateArticle` action  on the `Default` controller.

Next will be your controlls. Now this is about as far as I am going cause your model doesnt make much sense.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateArticle", "Default"))
{
    //form contolls here
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => modelItem.TitleIds, new SelectList(ViewBag.TitleNames as System.Collections.IEnumerable, "TitleId", "Title.TitleText"), "No: " + (string)ViewBag.MagNo, new { id = "TitleIds" })
        break;
    }
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
})
```

From here your on your own. I would suggest reading up on the basic tutorials using MVC

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-3

Answer (score 0):

You may use ajax posting and replace @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "CreateArticle") with a jQuery click event.
Just place the selected value in the parameter of the post URL.